# Простейшая валидация e-mail на JS

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

При передачи в функции id с числовым именем все работает на "ура", НО когда id состоит из букв, консоль сразу даёт ошибку "UnCaught TypeError".

Есть очень небольшая и простая форма:

```html
<form name = "svyaz" action = "" method = "post">
        <input onblur="checkEmailValid(11)" id = "11" name = "email" type = "email">
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
    </form>
```

Скрипт вызываемой функции при потере фокуса на input:

```js
function checkEmailValid(inputID) {
  var email_value = document.getElementById(inputID).value;
  if (email_value != '') {
    var pattern = /^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\._-]*[a-z0-9]*@([a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]+/i;
    if (email_value.search(pattern) != 0) alert('ВНИМАНИЕ! Введеный email адрес не соответствует общим стандартам.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkEmailValid(11)
```

заменить на (взять id в кавычки, тогда будет и буквы принимать)

```
checkEmailValid('11')
```